Should always capitalise 'I'?
when I'm using it to refer to yourself, Should always capitalise 'I'?
For Example)

If I continue to write my English diary, I believe my English will get better. (O)

If i continue to write my English diary, I believe my English will get better. (X)



Should always use uppercase "I"?

Why is the pronoun "I" capitalized?

This question was closed: I or i, which one is correct?

Do we have to use the capital letter for "I" letter in these case?

Always in public contexts. Texting to your friends on your phone? not necessary

The question lacks basic research.  The question of "why" may be interesting, but it's not directly relevant to learning English.  Is "cat" always spelled "c a t"?  Why is is spelled like that?  Can I spell it "kat" or "kit" or "kyat"?  What about if "cat is the first word in a sentence, can I spell it "Kat"?  What if it's a male cat, is that the same?  What about ....  These are all easily answered by a dictionary that shows only one standard spelling. The same dictionaries will show only one standard spelling of "I".
